# ldconfig not following user-created symbolic link

Tags: symlink, dynamic-linking

I'm attempting to run Inkscape 0.48.4-15 (armv7) which is installed via pacman from Arch Linux ARM.

```
$ inkscape
inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As expected, the shared object is not available in /usr/lib:

```
$ ll /usr/lib | grep libMagick+
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       30 Jun  5 03:04 libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so ->     libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       30 Jun  5 03:04 libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4 -> libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   379428 Jun  5 03:06 libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
```

So I make a symbolic link linking *.so.3 to *.so.4.0.0:

```
$ sudo ln -s libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0 libMagick++-6.Q16HD.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       30 Jun  5 03:04 libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so -> libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       30 Jun  6 15:15 libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.3 -> libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       30 Jun  5 03:04 libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4 -> libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   379428 Jun  5 03:06 libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
```

and verify that *.so.3 is indeed linked to *.so.4.0.0.

```
$ readlink -f libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.3
/usr/lib/libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
```

Now I reconfigure the dynamic linker run time bindings and rerun Inkscape:

```
$ sudo ldconfig 
$ ldd $(which inkscape) | grep libMagick++
libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.3 => /usr/lib/libMagick++-6.Q16HDRI.so.3 (0x75cf9000)
```

Why is `*.so.3` linking to itself and not following the symbolic link created earlier?

Comment: To be clear, with any of the derivative Arch distros (and Arch proper), it's almost _never_ a good idea to go manually poking around in `/usr`. Odds are, you need to run a full system upgrade which will include the so-name bumps so that `inkscape` works correctly.

Comment: Silly me, Inkscape runs just fine with the modified symbolic link; I mistook the long startup due to the "supposed" mislinkage of *.so.3 when in reality it's probably due to the lack of RAM and slow SD card read speeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ldd not following symlinks. It show only path, where it find library. 
ldd - diagnostic instrument and if it follow symlinks that impede diagnostic.

Comment: I am trying to solve a similar problem. What I've experienced: the symlinks won't work if they are used to similar sharedlib version bridging *from a different directory*. They should exist next to the hooked library. I.e. `ln -svf /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.55 /usr/local/lib/libicuuc.so.53` doesn't work, it should be in /usr/lib (very logic).

Comment: google: LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I prefer system-wide solutions with `/etc/ld.so.conf`, I didn't try the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (and also not LD_PRELOAD), but I don't think they would solve it or they would be the correct solution if yes, it is a deviation from the normal system behavior.